# How to bind an <input> to another <input> in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

**TL;DR:** binding an input-field to a second input-field results in not being able to get the value of the second input-field through its FormControl, unless the second input-field has been changed directly by the user, in which case the FormControl has the correct value, as expected -- I'm probably making a mistake with the type of binding?

**Full explanation:**

So I have this form:

```
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" [formControl]="artistForm.controls['name']" />

<label for="slug">Slug:</label>
<input type="text" id="slug" [formControl]="artistForm.controls['slug']" />
```

I want to achieve that whatever a user enters in input#name also appears in input#slug, but going through a slug-pipe or slug-function which creates a URL-friendly version of the name.

For example: '50 Cent' turns into '50-cent' and 'Bué the Warrior' to 'bue-the-warrior'. Pretty much the way slugs in WordPress are generated automatically.

So I tried binding the value of input#name to input#slug like this:

```
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" [formControl]="artistForm.controls['name']" />

<label for="slug">Slug:</label>
<input type="text" id="slug" (value)="{{ artistForm.controls['name'].value | slug }}" [formControl]="artistForm.controls['slug']" />
```

This works for the input-field directly, but the value-property of the formControl associated with it only gets updated when the input-field has been edited directly.

I want to generate a slug from the name-field, but still allow the user to change the value of the slug-field manually. How do I fix this?

[image: FormControl from the input#slug doesn't contain the current value]

EDIT: updated to latest Angular-version, didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by **Volodymyr Bilyachat** helped me a great deal, but it didn't work without some adjustments. He was totally right that I had to update slug in the typescript file instead of my template. When using the valueChanges-observable on the formGroup however, I got this error:

```
Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Of course, because all changes in the entire form were subscribed to, which results in an endless loop. So I played around with the code and this worked flawlessly:

```
this.formGroup.get('name').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  const slug = slugify(value); // slugify turns a string into a slug
  this.addArtistForm.get('slug').patchValue(slug);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using form group. So you should do it using forms. Listen to changes and if there is change with name and slug is not set them update slug

```
this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe((value)={
  if(!value.slug && value.name) this.formGroup.patch({slug: value.name});
});
```

Then fix `[formControl]="artistForm.controls['name']"` to be `[formControl]="name"` and do the same for slug

PS. Replace **formGroup** with your property name